# Cannot Figure out how to Properly Use APIs

Tags: javascript, html, api, http, get

So I am trying to create a website that sends a letter to a local congressman. The website consists primarily of a form that, upon clicking "Submit," should return a representative to contact using the Google Civic Info API. I am pretty new to HTTP communication, so I am not sure why, when trying to use GET, I'm getting a 403 error.

I don't even know if I'm using the API properly. The goal here is to submit an address (along with additional information), send that data to the API, and have it return a congressman based on the user's submitted information.

Link to Google Civic Info API: https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/representatives/representativeInfoByAddress

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Lob Application</title>

<link href = "stylesheet.css" rel = "stylesheet" >
</head>

<body>
 <div id = formInput class = "container-fluid">
 <form name = "submitDataForm" method = "GET" onsubmit="getData()">
  Name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "name"><br>
  Address Line 1:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "addressLineOne"><br>
  Address Line 2:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "addressLineTwo"><br>
  City:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "city"><br>
  State:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "state"><br>
  Zip Code:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "zip"><br>
  Message:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "message"/><br>
  <input id = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
</form>
</div>
<script src="processData.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function getData(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives/", false);
xhr.send(null);
console.log(xhr.status);
console.log(xhr.statusText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you reached the daily quota limit for API usage. You have to signup through the Google Developers Console and obtain a valid API_KEY.

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/standard_errors) for understanding your error message and to [this page](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/using_api) for understanding how to use the API